# Fabric An exception has occured; Error writing request

Tags: unity-game-engine, twitter-fabric, google-fabric

```
"[Fabric] An exception has occured; Error writing request: The authentication or decryption has failed.
UnityEngine.Debug:LogWarning(Object)
Fabric.Internal.Editor.Utils:Warn(String, Object[]) (at Assets/Fabric/Editor/FabricUtils.cs:18)
Fabric.Internal.Editor.Controller.PluginController:OnLoginError(Exception, Action`1) (at Assets/Fabric/Editor/GUI/Controller/PluginController.cs:537)
Fabric.Internal.Editor.Controller.<Login>c__AnonStorey3A:<>m__A0(Exception) (at Assets/Fabric/Editor/GUI/Controller/PluginController.cs:564)
Fabric.Internal.Editor.Detail.<CreateCoroutine>c__Iterator4:MoveNext() (at Assets/Fabric/Editor/GUI/Detail/AsyncTaskRunner.cs:106)
Fabric.Internal.Editor.Detail.AsyncTaskRunner`1:Update() (at Assets/Fabric/Editor/GUI/Detail/AsyncTaskRunner.cs:143)
UnityEditor.EditorApplication:Internal_CallUpdateFunctions()
"
```

I am entering right password, I even try changing new password via dashboard, I am able to login to fabric via brower but not via Unity.

Comment: Mike from Fabric here. You'll probably need to email us at support(at)fabric(dot)io for account issues.

Comment: I am in contact with your support team via mail, I received follow back for 2days then no replies.

Comment: @MikeBonnell its been two months, I am still stuck.

Comment: Hey @idurvesh - I took a look and it looks like we last sent a response on June 22nd, but we didn't see a reply back from that. I've resent our reply from the 22nd.

Comment: Oh so sorry, I think I missed that out on.Thank you for checking it out.Hope the problem get solve.Game is going live this saturday :)